# How to remove spaces between text in a single column with notepad plus

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a file like this with user names

```
Alexandra               Chaidez
Alexis                  Riley
Anela                   Salkic
Anna                    Maloney
April                   Szymanski
Areli                   Morales
```

I want to remove the extra spacing in between names to a single space like this

```
Alexandra Chaidez
Alexis Riley
Anela Salkic
Anna Maloney
April Szymanski
Areli Morales
```

I have searched and cant find anything that will do this please help!!

Comment: Have you looked into regular expressions?

Comment: notepad++ supports PCRE style regular expressions for search and replace. I would recommend to move this question to SuperUser.

Comment: This question would be appropriate for SuperUser, but it's not off-topic here. Notepad++ is a tool used for programming, and [the help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) says that questions regarding software tools used by programmers are on-topic here on SO as well.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the regex:

```
[ \t]+
```

and replace everything found with a single space character.

Answer (score 2):

For "Find What"

```
(\w+) +(\w+)
```

For "Replace With" (notice the space between)

```
$1 $2
```

Then set the Search Mode to "Regular Expression".

[See a demo of this](http://regexr.com/397go).